Why would points render in a Highcharts Stock chart when changing range selection?
Question: why would points appear on a Stock chart in Highcharts instead of just plot lines?
I'm playing with the Stock chart module in Highcharts in a Dashboard and I noticed that when I expand or contract the range selection in certain ways then points appear where there were none:

You can try this here: https://jsfiddle.net/zroq19nc/1/
I think I must be missing something when configuring the chart; here's its component entry in the dashboard:
{
  "renderTo": "stock-cell",
  "type": "Highcharts",
  "chartConstructor": "stockChart",
  "connector": {
    "id": "example-budget-data",
    "columnAssignment": [
      {
        "seriesId": "Total Spend",
        "data": ["d", "Total"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "sync": {
    "highlight": true
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "useHTML": true
  },
  "chartOptions": {
    "chart": {
      "className": "highcharts-stock-chart"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Total Spend"
    },
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Total Spend",
        "id": "total-spend"
      }
    ]
  }
}

My browser chrome://version:

Google Chrome:    128.0.6613.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision: d6209c7e65ea9d64ce403e9de18f8915e2f8708a-refs/branch-heads/6613@{#1712}
OS:   Windows 11 Version 23H2 (Build 22631.4169)


Could you provide more details on which OS and browser does this problem occur? I've tested on Windows 11 and Chrome, Edge and Firefox browsers and unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce this issue.

@jedrzejruta - Added to description but note that I can make this happen on other systems as well. The trick is to take shrink the left range slider to the mid-point, let mouse button up, then click and drag back to the far left ... points / dots appear. Which is strange because I don't think this chart ever renders points ... something to do with styledMode in a dashboard?

Apologies for a late response, it seem that I've missed the notification about your comment. Indeed, it seems to be a bug that's strictly related to accessibility module, which tries to somehow render the markers. I've already opened a ticket on GitHub, where you can track it's status: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/21915
